# c# Upload to ftp with not created directorys on ftp server

Tags: c#, ftp, upload

This is the path I am trying to upload to the ftp server:

**_ftp://ftp-server/products/productxx/versionxx/releasexx/delivery/data.zip**

The problem is that the folders **"productxx/versionxx/releasexx/delivery/"** do not exist on the server.

Can I create them automatically while uploading the .zip file in c#

My coding at the moment is:

```
                FtpWebRequest request =
                    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathToFtp);
                // Method set to UploadFile 
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                // set password and username
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                // write MemoryStream in ftpStream 
                using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    memoryStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
                }
```

I am getting the System.Net.WebException: "**Can't connect to FTP: (553) File name not allowed**" at "**using (Stream ftpStream =request.GetRequestStream())**"

but if my pathToFtp is **_ftp://ftp-server/products/data.zip** it´s working well

Answer (score 1):

One of the request methods available is `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory`. You should be able to use that to do what you want.

Something like this (though I've not tested it), should do the trick:

```
async Task CreateDirectory(string path)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;

    using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Created: {path}");
    }
}
```

It's answered in more detail here [How do I create a directory on ftp server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860638/how-do-i-create-a-directory-on-ftp-server-using-c)

Comment: thank you, it not give a method witch create the directory directly if is not exist iam right?

Comment: There are `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory` and `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails` request methods which could help you with that. You could just try to create the directory regardless and handle the response.

As far as I'm aware there isn't a "create if doesn't exist" command.

Comment: What the point of using `await request.GetResponseAsync()`? Use `request.GetResponse()` directly.